# Weighted average with multiple weights and groups python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a beginner in Python and I am trying to improve my code - so I would appreciate some advice on how to improve the efficiency of the following.

I have the following dataset:

```
petdata = {
    'animal' : ['dog', 'cat', 'fish'],
    'male_1' : [0.57, 0.72, 0.62],
    'female_1' : [0.43, 0.28, 0.38],
    'age_01_1': [0.10,0.16,0.15],
    'age_15_1':[0.17,0.29,0.26],
    'age_510_1':[0.15,0.19,0.19],
    'age_1015_1':[0.18,0.16,0.17],
    'age_1520_1':[0.20,0.11,0.12],
    'age_20+_1':[0.20,0.09,0.10],
    'male_2' : [0.57, 0.72, 0.62],
    'female_2' : [0.43, 0.28, 0.38],
    'age_01_2': [0.10,0.16,0.15],
    'age_15_2':[0.17,0.29,0.26],
    'age_510_2':[0.15,0.19,0.19],
    'age_1015_2':[0.18,0.16,0.17],
    'age_1520_2':[0.20,0.11,0.12],
    'age_20+_2':[0.20,0.09,0.10],
    'weight_1': [10,20,30],
    'weight_2':[40,50,60]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(petdata)
```

I want to calculate a weighted average for the animals in my dataset using weight_1 for all the variable that end with "_1" and weight_2 for all the variables that end with "_2".

I am doing it in this way at the moment:

```
df['male_wav_1']=np.nansum((df['male_1']*df['weight_1'])/df['weight_1'].sum())
df['female_wav_1']=np.nansum((df['female_1']*df['weight_1'])/df['weight_1'].sum())


df['male_wav_2']=np.nansum((df['male_2']*df['weight_2'])/df['weight_2'].sum())
df['female_wav_2']=np.nansum((df['female_2']*df['weight_2'])/df['weight_2'].sum())
```

And this is for every single column in my dataframe (i.e. age_01_1_wav, age_15_1_wav...)  I realise this is not very neat, so can anyone give me some advice on how to improve the process?

I have tried to:

- reshape the data from wide to long
- define a function for the weighted average

But I was unsuccessful with both. The issue not in the reshaping, I can do that, but they I am not clear on how to apply the different weights to the different groups I have in my data.

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I assume that the 'animals' column is your index, so for the sake of looking like a table, I made it the index:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
petdata = {
    # All of your data ^ above
}

df = pd.DataFrame(petdata)  # Creates the DF from your dictionary
df.set_index('animal',inplace=True) # Sets the 'animal' column as the index
```

I would start with breaking your DataFrame up into two parts: df_1 and df_2

```
# Uses list comprehension to create a list of all column names with a given string
# in the name, and uses this list to get a sub-DataFrame for each
df_1 = df[[name for name in df.columns if '_1' in name]]
df_2 = df[[name for name in df.columns if '_2' in name]]
```

Rather than create a new Series (column) in your DataFrame for each and every Series that already exists, I would rather create a new row that is the weighted average (wav) for each column. This will not be as pretty since the new row will not be an animal, yet the index 'wav' will be in the animal column.

Generate two lists of the weighted averages using list comprehension and the equation you were using:

```
wav_1 = [np.nansum(df[col]*df_1['weight_1'])/np.nansum(df_1['weight_1']) for col in df_1.columns]
wav_2 = [np.nansum(df[col]*df_1['weight_2'])/np.nansum(df_1['weight_2']) for col in df_2.columns]
```

Then append this data to the two DataFrames using your new 'wav' label:

```
df_1.loc['wav'] = wav_1
df_2.loc['wav'] = wav_2
```

Note that there is junk data in the 'wav'-'weight_x' box. It is the weighted average of your weights.

Welcome to Python! Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Python zip() function to make some quick calculations.

```
    petdata = {
        'animal' : ['dog', 'cat', 'fish'],
        'male_1' : [0.57, 0.72, 0.62],
        'age_20+_2':[0.20,0.09,0.10],
        'weight_1': [10,20,30],
        'weight_2':[40,50,60]
    }
weight_1 = petdata.get('weight_1')
male_1 = petdata.get('male_1')
for sales, costs in zip(weight_1, male_1):
    profit =sales * costs / sales
    print(f'Total profit: {profit}')

Total profit: 0.57
Total profit: 0.72
Total profit: 0.62
```

Comment: I still would have to do this for every single variable though? i.e. zip(weight_1, female_1), zip(age_01_1) etc. so I dont think it improves the efficiency much?